# Adding Searchbar to NavigationBar but TableViewCells not loading information

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar

I used to have a UISearchDisplayController in my TableViewController but I have recently changed it to a UISearchBar and added it to my NavigationBar.
I have added a UISearchBar to my Navigation titleView because I want it to be similar to the latest Twitter App. The issue that I am currently having is that I do not know how to display the search results in the table view. I can see that the searches are being made because I NSLogged searchbar.text. When I was using UISearchDisplayController it had a SearchResultsTableView but now I don't know how to make it display on the table view. Anyone have any guidance or help? Anything is appreciated.

Note: I have seen tutorials and post about adding search bar to navigation bar or using uisearchdisplaycontroller with a table view. I have tried adding the UISearchDisplayController to the navigationbar but it doesn't seem to work either. I'm using a UISearchBar and want it to update my table view controller. Here is an image to how twitter's search looks: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjCcM.png

Comment: Hi Jay, I'm having the exact same issue.  See my post

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20019608/searchbar-in-navigation-bar-not-working.  

Did you find an answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply make a `UITableView` which will display your search results, make your view controller implement `UITableViewDelegate` and `DataSource`. And if you want to make a live search then in searchbar `-(void) searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText` reload your table view with new data or reload it  in `- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar` if you want static search. I don't think twitter or linkedin apps use `searchDisplayController` - they just use custom search based on `UISearchBar` delegates as I described, because `UISearchDisplay` controller is quite limited when you want full search customiztion. I very rarely use it because of it.

Comment: I have done it the way you have described but it hides my navigation bar. If I add self.navigationController.navigationBar.isHidden = NO; inside searchDisplayControllerDidBeginSearch it hides the navigationBar for a second, almost like a flicker or twitch, and also comes back un-re-sized.

Comment: @JayNixon just add this to your `viewDidLoad`: `self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;` But I describe the way without any use of UISearchDisplayController - just custom table view and search bar with two delegates.read attentively.

Comment: Ahh, sorry I must have read that wrong. But can I add UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource inside a UITableViewController? Seems weird lol.

Comment: you can use the same delegate method. Just check tableView in it.E.g. in cellForRowAtIndexPath: `if ([tableView isEqualTo: searchTable]){....}`

Comment: My mind is blown! How do I hide the searchTable or dismiss the keyboard when the "x" or cancel button is clicked?

Comment: @JayNixon you have delegate methods for this: - `(void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar` - just make `searchTable.hidden = YES` in it and you are done. UISearchDisplayController it is just an extended and ready for use variation of the method I describe but it is too limited and hard to customize.

Comment: Sorry to keep bugging you, but I can't seem to dismiss the keyboard even when I hide the searchTable. I've tried [self.view endEditing:YES]; and [searchBar endEditing:YES]; as well as [searchBar resignFirstResponder]; and none of these work. Any ideas?